# Tipsy jQuery Tooltip Plugin - Is it possible to use more than one style?

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the jQuery Tipsy tooltip plugin (http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/). I have it working fine.

However, I am unable to use more than one style (CSS). I need to use 3 differently styled tooltips on my site. I can only manage to use the one style.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made the changes and applied a patch to the owner. Please take a look at the following patch which will allow customized style.

**JS**

https://github.com/rakesh-sankar/tipsy/blob/patch-1/src/javascripts/jquery.tipsy.js

**CSS**

https://github.com/rakesh-sankar/tipsy/blob/patch-2/src/stylesheets/tipsy.css

Now call like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
        $('a[rel=tipsy]').tipsy({clsStyle: 'blue'});
    });
</script>
```

Your CSS should read:

```
.blue-tipsy {.....}

.blue-tipsy-inner {....}

.blue-tipsy-arrow {....}
```

See [working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/UJjq5/9/)

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your help. However, being a noob, I'm unable to get it working. I copied you JS and renamed my CSS. I also added the function. however, it is not working for me. I would like to call this: $('#header .buttons li#add').tipsy({fade: true, gravity: 'e'});. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @User159025 Can you show me any error? Or show the page where I could see and find the exact problem.

Comment: Hi Rakesh. There is no error as such, the tooltip is just not showing any more. I think the issue is how I am calling the jquery. I would like to use $('#header .buttons li#add').tipsy({fade: true, gravity: 'e'}); whereas you have $('a[rel=tipsy]').tipsy({clsStyle: 'blue'});. Where my issue is, is that I do not know how to make your modified code work with my code. Once again, thanks for your help.

Comment: @User159025, please see it [working here](http://jsfiddle.net/srakesh/UJjq5/8/) - . Use the following [JS](https://raw.github.com/rakesh-sankar/tipsy/master/src/javascripts/jquery.tipsy.js) &  [CSS](https://raw.github.com/rakesh-sankar/tipsy/master/src/stylesheets/tipsy.css)

Comment: Also, see this - http://jsfiddle.net/UJjq5/9/ for having different color on tool-tips

Answer (score 10):

There is no need to fork tipsy, it already handles it via the 'className' option. Any classes you specify there will be added to the outermost div of the tooltip.

For example, if you want to change the tooltip background and arrow colours to blue, call tipsy like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('a[rel=tipsy]').tipsy({className: 'my-class'});
    });
</script>
```

Then add this CSS:

```
.my-class .tipsy-inner { background-color: blue; }

.my-class .tipsy-arrow-n { border-bottom-color: blue; }
.my-class .tipsy-arrow-s { border-top-color: blue; }
.my-class .tipsy-arrow-e { border-left-color: blue; }
.my-class .tipsy-arrow-w { border-right-color: blue; }
```

From reading the tipsy source, it looks like you can even give it a callback (accepting the selected element as a parameter), so that you can dynamically add classes.